# What are some easy to use resources and/or techniques for tracking down web javascript errors?

Tags: javascript, error-messaging

I just chased down wrong bugs for quite a while because code like

```
fetch("./garbage error message.json")
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(res => { resourceLocations = res })
```

gave the error message (firefox browser)

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

The real error was that `fetch` may have a different local directory than an `import * from ...` statement in the same file if the file itself is imported.

I've come to realize I waste way too much time on trivial javascript errors, and wanted to ask for ways to remedy that.

Comment: The answer: experience....

Comment: Here's a helpful resource: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript

Answer (score 1):

After the fact, I checked to see if the error message on chrome was any better, and got the following error messages instead:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

which is a lot more helpful. Checking error messages on multiple browsers was not a strategy I'd employed before, but it would've helped me here.

A less easy solution I'm considering is learning either Nim or TypeScript to help with dynamic typing errors, but I can't vouch for what I haven't tried.